# How to copy text of rows in jqxgrid while making it remain uneditable

Tags: jqxgrid

I am using jqxgrid for my application.I want to copy text of a row in jqxgrid (to use it for search etc) but the text should remain uneditable also(ie read only).I got some properties of jqxgrid but using them the text is also becoming editable in addition to copyable.Can someone please suggest me any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Select a row or rows and press Ctrl+C to copy the text into the clipboard.